# Heroku Deploy Images Reset

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I have an rails app deployed to Heroku. It has image uploads. After deployed to heroku again, i am unable to see old images that are uploaded.

Is heroku reset images folder when app is re-deployed? Please tell me the reason behind it.

Comment: did you do `run rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production` before you deployed to heroku?

Comment: Yes I did. Thanks, I got the reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Background

Heroku uses an ['ephemeral file system'](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem), which from an application architecture point of view should be considered as read-only - it is discarded as soon as the dyno is stopped or restarted (which, along with other occasions, occurs after each push), and is also not shared between multiple dynos.

This is fine for executing code from, as most application data is stored in a database that is independent of the dynos. However, for file uploads this presents a problem, and so any uploads should not be stored directly in the dyno filesystem.

#### Solution

The simplest solution is to use something like Amazon S3 as your file upload storage solution, and, if using a gem like *Paperclip*, this is natively supported within the gem. There is a great overview article in the Heroku Dev Center about using S3 and Heroku (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3), which leads into an article contributed by Thoughtbot (the developers of Paperclip) on implemenation specifics within a Rails app (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/paperclip-s3)